# MongoDB aggregate, slow query even with indexed sort parameter

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, aggregation-framework

I've got the following query:

```
db.Visitor.aggregate([
  {"$sort":{"updatedAt":-1}},
  {"$match":{
    "$and":[
      {"events.platformId":"8"},
      {"events.applicationId":{"$in":["354","325","373","177","379","417","415","416"]}},
      {"events.date":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-01-26 15:23:00")}},
      {"events.date":{"$lte":ISODate("2018-01-26 23:59:59")}}
    ]
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "events":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$events",
        "as":"event",
        "cond":{
          "$and":[
            {"$eq":["$$event.platformId","8"]},
            {"$in":["$$event.applicationId",["354","325","373","177","379","417","415","416"]]},
            {"$gte":["$$event.date",ISODate("2018-01-26 15:23:00")]},
            {"$lte":["$$event.date",ISODate("2018-01-26 23:59:59")]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$limit":15},
], {"maxTimeMS": 2500}).pretty()
```

And it fails as it reaches the max execution time. If I take the sort away, it returns in terms of milliseconds.

I thought it could be an index issue, but it already exists:

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "updatedAt" : -1
            },
            "name" : "expiration_ttl",
            "ns" : "analytics.Visitor",
            "expireAfterSeconds" : NumberLong(1296000)
    }
```

Do you have any clue?

Thanks :)

EDIT:
After a weekend of thoughts, I came up with the idea to create a step in the pipeline between `$sort` and `$match`, creating an additional `$match` filtering the documents in the collection having `updatedAt` in the range specified in `events.date` or `requests.date` (the former `$match`). In this way the query won't take lots of time, being the resulting collection much more smaller than the original one, letting the match work even without having indexes on every match condition's attributes.

Comment: does `db.Visitor.explain("allPlansExecution").aggregate([...])` shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$sort` stage to the end, right before `$limit`. It should trigger [sort-limit coalescence](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-limit-coalescence):

```
db.Visitor.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    ...
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "events":{
      ...
    },
    "updatedAt": 1
  }},
  {"$sort":{"updatedAt":-1}},
  {"$limit":15},
], {"maxTimeMS": 2500}).pretty()
```

Benchmark it with different indexes using `hint` option:

```
db.Visitor.aggregate(
    [...], 
    {"maxTimeMS": 2500, hint: "expiration_ttl"}
).pretty()
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your suggestion, but it seems it doesn't recognize the "hint" option: `unrecognized field 'hint'` (using MongoDB 3.4.9-2.9)

Comment: @Jack You are out of luck then. 3.4 doesn't support hints, nor proper `explain` for aggregation. Pipeline optimisation was much worse as well. Is there any chance to migrate to 3.6?

Comment: Not in the near future... we should, but not right now. Doesn't moving `$sort` at the bottom make MongoDB process `$match` before, and thus running the matches without indexes - making the query slow? I put the `$sort` at the begninning right for that purpose

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that. Apart from sorting, you do matching, which probably results with collection scan. If you have high cardinality for events, it may be better to use index on these fields. Hard to say without `explain` results. If the dataset is not huge, you might be able to export-import it to v3.6 instance for profiling.

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for all the replies. I've found the solution, but I'm going to accept yours as I found the solution with information not in the question. Thanks for the help though :)